# RecyclerView ripple effect not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add Ripple Effect to RecyclerView's item. I had a look online, but could not find what I need. I have tried android:background attribute to the RecyclerView itself and set it to "?android:selectableItemBackground" but it did not work.:

adapter template is shown in below

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/text_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"

>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/u_key"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Item"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/u_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_text_size"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Item"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size" />



<View
    android:id="@+id/bottomline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the LinearLayout parent view background, I saw that the background attribute is not correct (you forgot the android between the question mark and the :attr).

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use ConstraintLayout, try this

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```